# Java Mockito and Delegation

Tags: java, delegates, mockito

I need to return new Date() each time I make a call to getLastModifiedDate.  I'm using this mock:

```
when(network.getLastModifiedDateOf(any(URL.class))).
            thenReturn(formatDate(new Date()));
```

However, every time getLastModifiedDateOf is called it returns the same date/time of when the test started. I think I need something like a C# delegate to call new Date() each time that mock is hit.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Look at [`Answer`](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/stubbing/Answer.html) callbacks, rather than direct return values.

```
when(...).thenAnswer(new Answer() {
    Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) {
        return formatDate(new Date());
    }
});
```

Comment: That did the trick, new to Mockito and all I had was the thenReturn hammer so the world looked like a nail.  Thanks.

Comment: Glad to help.  Be aware that needing to use `Answer` can be a warning sign--tests might benefit from more locked down data.

Comment: Note that in Mockito 1.9.0 you will be able to write `when(network.getLastModifiedDateOf(any(URL.class))).then(returnFormattedDate(new Date()));` where `then` is an alias to `thenAnswer` and `returnFormattedDate` will of course be a custom method that returns an `Answer`.